# RuntimeException: getParameters failed (empty parameters)

Tags: android, firebase, android-layout, kotlin, android-fragments

I am Working on Android Application in Which I am using the QR Library
`implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.13` The Issue I am Facing is as I Scan The QR Code With Flash and Go to Next Activity After the Results Received ,like this

```
if (resultstring != null) {
        String currentDateTimeString = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), QRScannedResultActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("sendedscannedcontent", resultstring);
        intent.putExtra("scannedtimeanddate", currentDateTimeString);
        startActivity(intent);
        resumeFun = true;
        playBeepSoundAndVibrate();
        getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.nav_default_enter_anim, R.anim.nav_default_pop_exit_anim);
    }
```

And When I come Back from second Activity to the Scanning Fragment Class It is Giving me the Exception Error of

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: getParameters failed (empty parameters)
    at android.hardware.Camera.native_getParameters(Native Method)
    at android.hardware.Camera.getParameters(Camera.java:1988)
    at me.dm7.barcodescanner.core.CameraUtils.isFlashSupported(CameraUtils.java:47)
    at me.dm7.barcodescanner.core.BarcodeScannerView.setFlash(BarcodeScannerView.java:153)
    at me.dm7.barcodescanner.core.BarcodeScannerView.setupCameraPreview(BarcodeScannerView.java:90)
    at me.dm7.barcodescanner.core.CameraHandlerThread$1$1.run(CameraHandlerThread.java:31)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6552)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857)
```

This Error Only Occur if and only If If I Scan QR With flash and Come Back. If I Scan **QR Normally without Flash** It Works Perfectly.

I have Gone through several Links But Got Nothing.

Comment: Seems a library issue its also reported. But this one is archived . You probably have to fix it yourself or find some alternative.

Comment: How Would I Get rid of this Error?